# pandas groupby and agg

Tags: pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Here are my data:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('gp_data.csv',sep= ";")
df2 = pd.read_csv('ms_data.csv',sep= ";")
#2.7.2
student_data = pd.concat([df1, df2])
#2.7.3 
df3 = pd.read_csv('gp_grades.csv',sep= ";")
df4 = pd.read_csv('ms_grades.csv',sep= ";")
#2.7.4
student_grades = pd.concat([df3, df4])
#2.7.5
student = pd.merge(left=student_grades, right=student_data, left_on='student_id', right_on='student_id')
```

*Q:Based on the address and guardian, do the following:*

*Define a function and use agg to apply the function to the traveltime column.*
*Find out the sum of the travel time for each group.*
*Do not use Pandas provide function for the answer, but you may use it to check.
Here are my codes below:*

```
#1
def travel(series):
  return sum(series == True)

print(student.groupby(['address','guardian']).agg({'traveltime' : travel}))

#2

print(student.agg({'traveltime':'sum'}))
```

In fact I don't know what kind of function it may need and not so sure whether the second question is satisfied. (print(student.agg({'traveltime':'sum'})))

Comment: I think in question missing sample data, maybe need `return sum(series)` or `return series.sum()` for `#1` ?

Comment: the output is same, return sum(series == True) or return sum(series). Any ideas?

Comment: hmm, maybe need for second `print(student.groupby(['address','guardian']).agg({'traveltime':'sum'}))`

Comment: Thank you , but how about the second question? Find out the sum of the travel time for each group.. So I deleted the groupby. ----> print(student.agg({'traveltime':'sum'}))

Comment: Hmmm, if need `Find out the sum of the travel time for each group.` why is groupby deleted ?

Comment: exactly..but groupby what? print(student.groupby(['      ']).agg({'traveltime':'sum'}))

Comment: hmmm, `['address','guardian']` ? Like `print(student.groupby(['address','guardian']).agg({'traveltime':'sum'}))` ? But hard to know without data, only guessing

Comment: I guess it must groupby the address and guardian. then the first question is apply the function to the traveltime column. my answer is right??

Comment: If use `print(student.groupby(['address','guardian']).agg({'traveltime':'sum'}))` for `#2` then both `#1, #2`  apply the function to the traveltime column.